# MySQL not responding?

Tags: server, mysql

I've managed to set up a running web server from Ubuntu a couple days ago, but for some reasons it doesn't work since this afternoon ?

MySQL seems to be stuck somehow, here is the status :

```
$ root@localhost:~# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-31 14:49:29 UTC; 18s ago
  Process: 856 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 31 14:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I tried to reboot the server, but it didn't change anything.

I've no idea why this is happening, since I didn't made changes on MySQL in the past hours. What could have had an effect are : I added Cloudflare to my website, or I also change the owner of all File/Folder of the wordpress installation (so it allows Wordpress to updates plugins etc.). Maybe this owner change had an impact on the fact that MySQL cannot connect any longer with root ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I somehow found out the solution : it was on my /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf configuration file. I had :

```
# [client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

where I should have had :

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

I found out by looking at sudo journalctl -xeu mysql, where I found these lines :

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jun 02 08:09:24 localhost mysql-systemd-start[18290]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Jun 02 08:09:24 localhost mysql-systemd-start[18290]: 2019-06-02T08:09:24.858095Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
Jun 02 08:09:24 localhost mysql-systemd-start[18290]: 2019-06-02T08:09:24.861413Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Indeed, I tried previously to set UTF8 as default but somehow forgot to un-comment the code [client], and it was preventing MySQL to start-up.